# Ajuda com script que traça rotas

Tags: shell-script

Fiz um script que traça a rota de um determinado IP, mas com o while indo até 50, mesmo que a conexão tenha um salto de 8 rotas, ele ira contar ate 50, como eu faço para parar o while quanto acabar a quantidade de rotas?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Digite um IP: "; read ip
count=1;
while [ $count -lt 50 ]; do
    ping $ip -t $count -c 1 | grep ^From | awk '{print $2}'

let count=$count+1;
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Podemos trabalhar com o [Exit Status](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) do seu comando, que é o valor retornado pela system call *waitpid*, e nos ajuda a entender se este foi bem sucedido ou não.

Neste caso, poderíamos adicionar o **operador lógico &&**, da seguinte forma:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Digite um IP: "; read ip
count=1;
while [ $count -lt 50 ]; do
    ping $ip -t $count -c 1 | grep ^From | awk '{print $2}' && break

let count=$count+1;
done
```

Explicação da linha alterada:

```
ping $ip -t $count -c 1 | grep ^From | awk '{print $2}' && break
```

[Só será executado o comando *break* caso o *ping* retorne 0 (zero).](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/list-cons.html#LISTCONSREF)

Dessa forma, assim que o ping encontrar o menor TTL, o loop será quebrado.

Prova de conceito simples para o ping:

```
$ ping google.com -t 9 -c 1
PING google.com (172.217.30.14) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from rio01s23-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.30.14): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=5.16 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.161/5.161/5.161/0.000 ms

$ echo $?
0

$ ping google.com -c 1 -t 8
PING google.com (172.217.30.14) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

$ echo $?
1
```